# How to make post excerpt as link using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make a post excerpt into a clickable link.

And structure of my website is as follows.

```
  <div class="post_widget">
    <a class="poast_thumbnail" href="example.com">
        <div class="thumbnail>
                <img ...>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="post">
        <div class="title">
            <a href="example.com">this is sample</a>
        </div>
        <div class="post_excerpt">
          <p> == $0
            "Hello world"
            ::after
          </p>
          <a class="read_more" href="https://example.com">read more</a>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I found the following JavaScript and modified it to suit my website.

```
<script>
const postExcerpts = document.querySelectorAll('.post .post_excerpt');

postExcerpts.forEach(postExcerpt => {
    const postUrl = postExcerpt.parentNode.querySelector('.title a').href;
    postExcerpt.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.href = postUrl;
    });
});
</script>
```

I've changed  .querySelector several times and tested it, but not working.

No errors appear in the chrome developer tools.

I'd like to hear some advice on which part I need to fix.

```js
const postExcerpts = document.querySelectorAll('.post .post_excerpt');

postExcerpts.forEach(postExcerpt => {
    const postUrl = postExcerpt.parentNode.querySelector('.title a').href;
    postExcerpt.addEventListener('click', () => {
        window.location.href = postUrl;
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="post">
    <div class="title">
        <a href="example.com">this is sample</a>
    </div>
    <div class="post_excerpt">
        <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated your question with a snippet version of your code and it does indeed redirect when you click on the text "Hello World". It may just be that you are expecting the entire box to be clickable, but are only assigning the event listener to the excerpt container which does not include the margins in the `<p>` element. Correct me if I'm wrong or explain what the expected behavior is in greater detail.

Comment: Hi, @Liftoff ,Thanks for answering. I checked your snippet and I knew the code to be working fine.

Nevertheless I would like to ask more question as it is not working on my website.

As your comment, "not include the margins in the <p> element", do you mean margin in css?

I guess the reason the code doesn't work has to do with the structure of my website.

So I updated the structure a bit more as seen in chrome developer tools, but when I tested it in the snippet, there was no problem.

I am still confused why the code not working...

Comment: I found the problem!! i am idiot. <script> was misspelled. Thank you.